# Generating bundles in Webpack in folders corresponding to source files

Tags: webpack, dynamic-loading, preact

I use webpack with preact-async-router which allows splitting and loading codebase into bundles.
It works well, but bundles are located in 1 folder and have flat structure. 
I expect performance issues for big number of bundles.

```
await import("app/module/page")
```

By default preact-async-router loads bundles from corresponding path.
I.e. if src/a/b/c.tsx then http get /a/b/bundle.11.js. 
I use publicPath: "/" workaround for that and any path is replaced with empty string, but that doesn't solve problem having big bundle folder.

```
  output: {
    filename: "./bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
```

I tried to play with filename and path keys using for them functions to generate dynamic output path, but it is not working. Function is called just once, cause there 1 entry file. Sub bundle files cannot be used as entry points (for page reload I use rewrite rules to load index.html if path points to 404).

There is no proper variable in brackets holding path to origin file.

So if there is a way to evaluate filename function for every file then publicPath could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to [`SplitChunksPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksname) which has details on how you can configure `optimization.splitChunks` to manage chunks.

Specifically, [`splitChunks.name`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksname) allows you to pass in a function to change the chunk name and this should permit you to move it on a subpath in the assets.

Side note: while it's possible to configure the output directory to be within your source directory, technically you should always be able to configure an output path outside (since `publicPath` and `outputPath` are independent). You can use  `copy-webpack-plugin` to move static sources into outputs.

This has some benefits, notably making it easier to configure VCS ignore patterns  and also being able to use `clean-webpack-plugin` to ensure you aren't accessing stale/keeping orphaned assets around.